# Where exactly to set cache expiration on css content?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

It seems that my browser checks for a new css on every request. Where and how do I indicate the time before checking for a new css?

Answer (score 1):

Using IIS7 add a far future expires header or cache-control header by following the directions in this [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661(WS.10).aspx).

I'm also a big fan of using the firefox plugin [YSLOW](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for testing this and other performance features of web sites.